# Kafka authorization

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, acl

I am new to kafka so please excuse me if this seems trivial.

I am trying to use authentication (kerberos) and authorization with kafka and wanted to check how kafka authorization works. I know it by default work via ACL rules written in Zookeeper.

I wanted to know whether authorization check happen on each read/write operation i.e., per message or is it done once per connection from producer/consumer

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/AbdelkrimHadjidj/paris-fod-meetup-kafka-security-101 >> but does not go into the run-time details; you may have to inspect the source code by yourself _(ZK can push notifications to its connected clients when `znodes` content has changed, though, hence it's possible to maintain an authorization cache client-side while keeping in sync)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorizations checks happen on each Kafka request. Every time the producer sends messages to Kafka, brokers will ensure that it has the correct ACLs. Same thing happens for consumers and other clients.

If you change ACLs, then the very next request will be evaluated against the updated rules.

---

Authentication on the other hand is perform once when the connection is established. There is some work in progress to revalidate authentication periodically for existing connections so that should be available at some point in the future.